# Como aplicar append en un runOnUiThread en Kotlin para Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo esta pedaso de codigo en Kotlin para Android y necesito aplicarle appned a la variable messageReceived, como puedo hacer

```
private fun updateReceivedMessage(newPayload: String) {
    runOnUiThread { messageReceived.text = newPayload }
}
```

Comment: en ves de = usa +=

Answer (score 0):

Si te encuentras dentro de una `Activity` puedes usar `runOnUiThread`  dentro de tu función `updateReceivedMessage()` de esta forma:

```
private fun updateReceivedMessage(newPayload: String) {
    this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {

        messageReceived.text = newPayload

    })

}
```